# How to use Provide/Inject to pass an array from a parent component to a grandchild component

Tags: vue.js, dependency-injection, vue-component, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I am attempting to use Provide/Inject functionality to enable a parent component to "provide" an array to a grandchild component, based on the following Vue 3 Composition API docs: https://vuejs.org/guide/components/provide-inject.html#working-with-reactivity

The array in my parent component looks like this:

```js
const arrayItems= [
  { name: 'itemOne' },
  { name: 'itemTwo' },
  { name: 'itemThree' },
  { name: 'itemFour' },
  { name: 'itemFive' },
]
```

The above documentation for Provide/Inject appears to only show examples of providing primitive types. Based on the concepts in the docs, I attempted to provide an array to a grandchild component, but the injected array doesn't appear to be rendering on the grandchild. Any idea how to set up Provide/Inject in order to pass the array to the grandchild component?

Here is my code so far:

Parent

```html
<template>
  <div class="h-full">
    <child />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { provide } from 'vue'
import { Child } from '@Child'

const arrayItems= [
  { name: 'itemOne' },
  { name: 'itemTwo' },
  { name: 'itemThree' },
  { name: 'itemFour' },
  { name: 'itemFive' },
]

export default {
  components: {
    Child
  },
  setup() {
    provide('navigation', arrayItems)

    return {
      arrayItems
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Child

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <grandchild />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { GrandChild } from '@'
export default {
    components: {
        GrandChild 
    }
}
</script>
```

GrandChild

```html
<template>
  <div>
     <ul>
       <li v-for="item in items" :key="item.id"></li>
     </ul>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { inject } from 'vue'
export default {
    setup() {
        const { items } = inject('navigation')

        return {
            items
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `GrandChild.vue`, you're destructuring the `inject`-ed value for an `items` property, but the `provide`-ed item is an `Array`, which has no such property.

#### Solution

Don't destructure the `inject`-ed value:

```js
// GrandChild.vue
export default {
  setup() {
    // const { items } = inject('navigation') ❌
    const items = inject('navigation') ✅
    ⋮
  },
}
```

[demo 1](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-troubleshooting-provide-inject?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FGrandChild.vue)

Or `provide` the array data in an object with an `items` property:

```js
// Parent.vue
export default {
  setup() {
    // provide('navigation', arrayItems) ❌
    provide('navigation', { items: arrayItems }) ✅
    ⋮
  }
}
```

[demo 2](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-troubleshooting-provide-inject-mqr1im?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FParent.vue)